# PowerShell Script Output Without Truncation

Tags: powershell

I have my PowerShell script as below in a file `myps.ps1`.

```
Invoke-Expression "terraform apply -auto-approve" -OutVariable COMMAND_OUTPUT 2>&1 >$null
```

Through this script I am trying to capture both standard error and standard output to a variable `$COMMAND_OUTPUT`. But when the `terraform apply` command throws an error, truncated error message ending with ellipsis (`...`) is getting captured in `$COMMAND_OUTPUT`.

How can I capture the entire PowerShell console output in my `$COMMAND_OUTPUT` variable without truncation.

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-Expression` is [considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) and almost always the wrong tool for whatever problem you're facing.

To capture command output (including errors) in a variable use something like this:

```
$COMMAND_OUTPUT = & terraform apply -auto-approve 2>&1
```